# Binding To Combobox But Error "Object reference..." in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, object, data-binding, binding, combobox

i want binding with combobox. but it's error **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

**This Code:**

```
Private Sub cbSection_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbSection.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim Find As Boolean = False
        Dim ds2 As New DataSet
        Dim sb2 As New StringBuilder
        Dim da2 As New SqlDataAdapter

        sb2.Remove(0, sb2.Length)
        sb2.Append("SELECT DISTINCT Team")
        sb2.Append(" FROM Employee")
        sb2.Append(" WHERE (Section='" & cbSection.SelectedValue & "')")
        sb2.Append(" ORDER BY Team")
        Dim sqlTeam As String = sb2.ToString()

        If Find = True Then
            ds2.Tables("Team").Clear() >>>>>>> This Error
        End If

        da2.SelectCommand.CommandText = sqlTeam
        da2.Fill(ds2, "Team")
        If ds2.Tables("Team").Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            Find = True
            With cbTeam
                .DisplayMember = "Team"
                .ValueMember = "Team"
                .DataSource = ds2.Tables("Team")
            End With
        Else
            Find = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

i check object it's all correct. but error now.

Thanks you for your time.:)

Comment: Apart from the error, you declared a boolean `Find` as False. Do you actually expect it to become `True` before this line `If Find = True Then` ??

Comment: The code above cannot reach the line you have signaled as the one with the error. However, if for chance, you get that line execute, then the `ds2` _LOCAL_ variable, has no table called "Team" until the DataAdapter.Fill method. Thus you can't call Clear on a non existing table (null reference).

Comment: Why are you even using a stringbuilder? And if it is empty, how can you call .Remove on it?